# Help with custom header command?

Tags: macros

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=5cm,yshift=00.00pt] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{black}%
      {#1}{#2}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{30pt}
}


% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\header{Name}{Surname}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is the output displayed in such a small font when I’m specifying  `\fontsize{40pt}{72pt}`? Can anybody help me get the output in a much larger font size?

Also, I’d like the word “surname” to be in bold, but I can’t get it. Any help with that?

Thank you all in advanced for your time.

Comment: `\fontsize{...}{...}` must be followed by `\selectfont` and for Computer Modern you need to add `\usepackage{fix-cm}` to get non standard sizes.

Comment: Use `\fontsize{40pt}{75pt} \selectfont`.

Comment: Thank you both for your useful comments. Adding `\selectofont` after the fontsize did the trick. However, I do not know where to add `\usepackage{fix-cm}` in my MWE.

Comment: Anywhere between `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` …

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t see it was a standard `\usepackage{…}` command. I obviously know where to place those… My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

% HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=5cm,yshift=00.00pt] (box) at (current page.north){};
        \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
            \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{black}%
            {\normalfont#1}{\bfseries#2} % <<<<---- changes to your code
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{30pt}
}


% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    \header{Name}{ Surname}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]